# University for Crypto grad study

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, quantum-cryptography, history

(I thought twice before asking this question and quite reluctant to type as well, but I think this would be helpful).

I am an undergrad student and choose theoretical computer science as my major. Now I want to pursue a grad study in cryptography and I want to know the best universities in this field of mathematics and research.

Comment: This question will almost certainly be closed, FYI. Some good crypto universities: MIT, Toronto, Waterloo,  Stanford, Bristol (England), ETH Zurich, UCSD, Texas, Georgia Tech, UC Davis... But grad study is really more about your advisor than any particular program. There are lots of very talented cryptographers at lesser-known schools, so don't be afraid to go to a non-top-10 school if the professor is perfect for you.

Comment: Most of the [IACR job postings](http://www.iacr.org/jobs/) these days are for students that want to get MS or PhD studying cryptography. Look through those, find a topic that interests you and you may be able to get your degree paid for. That said, the question is off-topic here, but I hope you've gotten some helpful inputs.

Comment: To add to some of the other posts, a big think you will need to do is narrow down what you mean when you say "Crypto". Crypto is very broad. Are you interested in symmetric crypto, public key crypto, homomorphic crypto, multiparty computation, cryptanalysis, applications of crypto, etc? Answering this will be a very important first step.

Answer (score 4):

If the school has graduate courses that interest you and you think you can do well in (i.e. for comprehensive exams), and there is a strong crypto research group there, I would recommend any school that satisfied these criteria. As you move through academics, it becomes more and more clear that the quality of your research is the most important, and it is less important where you are. Some obvious non-starters: teaching schools, schools with no crypto faculty, schools with no crypto grad courses (there should be at least one or two).